# Problem writing bool converter in ponyorm

Tags: python, ponyorm

My database stores bool values as CHAR(1), T=True, F=False.  I'm trying to write a converter so that I can use bool values in my python code and have pony handle the conversion to the database.

Here's what I have:

```
from pony import orm
from pony.orm.dbapiprovider import BoolConverter

class DALBoolConverter(BoolConverter):
    def validate(self, val, obj=None):
        print 'VALIDATOR', val, obj
        return val

    def py2sql(self, val):
        print 'py2sql', val
        return 'T' if val else 'F'

    def sql2py(self, val):
        print 'sql2py', val
        return True if val == 'T' else False

    def sql_type(self):
        print 'sql_type'
        return 'CHAR(1)'

db.provider.converter_classes.append((bool, DALBoolConverter))

class AuthUser(db.Entity):
    _table_ = 'auth_user'

    first_name = orm.Required(str)
    last_name = orm.Required(str)
    email = orm.Optional(str)
    password = orm.Optional(str)
    registration_key = orm.Optional(str)
    reset_password_key = orm.Optional(str)
    registration_id = orm.Optional(str)
    active = orm.Required(bool)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with db_session:
        a = AuthUser[1]
        print a.active  #  returns True
        a.active = False
```

You can see I have some print statements in there but they are never executed.  I'm getting the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jim/dev/qlf/qlf/pony_model.py", line 720, in <module>
    """
  File "/home/jim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 476, in __exit__
    db_session._commit_or_rollback(exc_type, exc, tb)
  File "/home/jim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 490, in _commit_or_rollback
    commit()
  File "/home/jim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 381, in commit
    rollback_and_reraise(sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/jim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 370, in rollback_and_reraise
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/jim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 379, in commit
    cache.flush()
  File "/home/jim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 1888, in flush
    if obj is not None: obj._save_()
  File "/home/jim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 5363, in _save_
    elif status == 'modified': obj._save_updated_()
  File "/home/jim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 5272, in _save_updated_
    cursor = database._exec_sql(sql, arguments, start_transaction=True)
  File "/home/jim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 945, in _exec_sql
    connection = cache.reconnect(e)
  File "/home/jim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 1776, in reconnect
    if not provider.should_reconnect(exc): reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/jim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 943, in _exec_sql
    try: new_id = provider.execute(cursor, sql, arguments, returning_id)
  File "<auto generated wrapper of execute() function>", line 2, in execute
  File "/home/jim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pony/orm/dbapiprovider.py", line 61, in wrap_dbapi_exceptions
    raise OperationalError(e)
pony.orm.dbapiprovider.OperationalError: (1292, "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'T  '")
```

...which probably makes sense because I don't think my DALBoolConverter is ever getting called.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to achieve your goal is to use [hybrid methods](https://docs.ponyorm.org/entities.html?highlight=hybrid#hybrid-methods-and-properties).

So you do

```
class AuthUser(db.Entity):
    _table_ = 'auth_user'

    first_name = orm.Required(str)
    last_name = orm.Required(str)
    email = orm.Optional(str)
    password = orm.Optional(str)
    registration_key = orm.Optional(str)
    reset_password_key = orm.Optional(str)
    registration_id = orm.Optional(str)
    active = orm.Required(str) # use str here

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active == 'T'
```

Then you might use

```
with db_session:
    a = AuthUser[1]
    print a.is_active
```

Comment: That's perfect. Sometimes you get so focused on one path that you can't see other, more obvious paths.

Thanks so much for your help.

Jim